# How to stop two inner divs from overlapping when screen width changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three blurbs that each contain an image, heading, paragraph and button (from top to bottom). My problem is that the paragraph begins to overlap the button when the screen size is expanded. The button location needs to remain consistent throughout each blurb. It's currently positioned as absolute with a bottom property of 40 pixels. I'm open to fixes with just HTML/CSS or Jquery. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```css
.history_link {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 599px;
}

.history_link h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.learn_btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.rs_caption p {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.history_link img {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding: 35px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="history_link col span_4">
  <div class="why_rs_link">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/history_icon.png" />
    <h3>Our History</h3>
    <div class="rs_caption">
      <p>Founded by teacher and mentor Patricia DeOrio, herself dyslexic, we’ve always understood what it takes to unlock the potential of children with learning differences.</p>
      <a href="http://riversideschool.rpmdevserver.com/our-history/">
        <h2 class="learn_btn">LEARN MORE</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[button with absolute positioning displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThwiD.jpg)

[button with absolute positioning with overlap when screen size expands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPh7j.jpg)

Comment: Is it OK for your case to specify `min-height` for that divs?

Comment: Absolute positioning takes elements out of the current document flow and are positioned relative to the closest positioned parent. If there are no positioned ancestor elements, then this will be relative to the viewport (browser window). In your screenshots there is no reason to use absolute positioning. Your design is three vertically stacked element in a container. Also, when you provide HTML examples please provided the generated markup (i.e. no PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioning takes elements out of the current document flow (don't take up space) and are positioned relative to the closest positioned ancestor. If there are no positioned ancestor elements, then the element will be positioned relative to the viewport (browser window). This is why your button overlays your text at different viewport sizes.

In your screenshots there is no reason to use absolute positioning. Your design is three vertically stacked element in a container. This the default flow of block level elements, taking up the full width of container element and start on its own line/row.

Top keep the button at the bottom you will need to ensure that each component only takes up a set amount of space, i.e setting heights on some sub components like the `p`. Though I would go for a `flexbox` solution myself so the design is less rigid because you do not have to set any heights.

`flex-grow: 1;` tells `p` to fill the remaining space of a container element, thus pushing the *Learn More* link to the bottom of the `.card` element.

Below is a demo of how you could simplify your markup and make it more semantic (don't use `h2` for a *Read More* link).

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.card img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.card p {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/fff">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat nihil accusamus numquam praesentium ipsum aspernatur deserunt.
    </p>
    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/fff">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300/fff">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat nihil accusamus numquam praesentium ipsum aspernatur deserunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat nihil accusamus numquam praesentium ipsum aspernatur deserunt.
    </p>
    <a href="#">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to explain this solution. It was very helpful. I worked it into my code this morning and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed width and height affects on responsiveness. Try replace it with padding or margin rules. Also you can set min(max)-height, min(max)-width. And be sure to use viewport;)